# Mapping ufw rule to iptables

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, ufw

I'm moving from ufw to iptables.

There is a default "limit" rule in ufw, which kicks in if an IP address initiates 6+ connections in 30 seconds (`sudo ufw limit ssh`). I use that limit rule for SSH traffic (port 22).

I've read so many different ways to do this in iptables, that it's just confusing. I'm unsure whether to use the `connlimit` or `limit` or some other module.

What is the simplest way to map this rule 1:1 to iptables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### **Using the `recent` extension**

Based on @Tomasz's idea, I created the rule in ufw and inspected the result in iptables. Seems ufw uses the `recent` extension:

```
:LOG_REJECT - [0:0]

-A INPUT      -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m recent --set
-A INPUT      -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m recent --update --seconds 30 --hitcount 6 -j LOG_REJECT
-A INPUT      -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22                                                                         -j ACCEPT
-A LOG_REJECT                                                     -m limit --limit 3/min                       -j LOG --log-prefix "[LIMITED SSH]"
-A LOG_REJECT                                                                                                  -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

#### **Using the `limit` extension**

Which is slightly neater/simpler:

```
:LOG_REJECT - [0:0]

-A INPUT      -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m limit --limit 12/minute -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT      -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW                            -j LOG_REJECT
-A LOG_REJECT                                                     -m limit --limit 3/minute  -j LOG --log-prefix "[LIMITED SSH]" --log-level 7
-A LOG_REJECT                                                                                -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

(Though I'm unsure if `icmp-port-unreachable` is a proper rejection message in this case.)

#### **Using the `connlimit` extension**

...maybe someone else can add that. :)

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: yes why ? A comment might be a better way to express disagreement.

Answer (score 2):

`ufw` manipulates on iptables, so since you're moving from ufw, I guess you can capture your iptables and see what ufw does there.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean? I'm looking for the iptables equivalent of ufw's `ufw limit ssh`

Comment: @lonix List iptables when ufw is active with this policy.